# Hortonworks Docker Sandbox HDP VM VirtualBox stuck on waiting for Ambria server Windows10

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I cannot seem to figure out why VirtualBox wont connect with Ambria agent on my laptop. I'm currently using version 2.6.4, but tried the older version and still had the same issue. I have tried different methods to solve the problem:

1) I applied the virtualbox's ip address, which I found in command front, to ports 8080 and 8888, which didnt due anything

2) Tried changing the network connection from NAT to Host-Only Adapter, which did nothing

3) Tried re-installing the package

I currently run Spyder to code in python in its own environment and have Anaconda3 installed in my computer. I don't know if any of this play's a factor

I have no idea how any of this works, so I have been trying random methods that I found on the internet, but nothing seems to work. Was hoping that someone would have encountered a similar issue. Please let me know if I should provide any further information with network connections, etc. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The Hortonworks sandbox should already have the correct network configurations in Virtualbox. `http://localhost:8080` should work

Comment: This is what I see when virtual box is booting up :  "ambari server not yet listening on http port 8080".  I don't know if this is causing the issue

Comment: I also reinstalled Windows10 on my computer, wiping out everything to see if that would fix the issue

Comment: I haven't used Windows recently with the VM, so I really can't say. But reinstalling Windows won't help with anything wrong with the bootability of the software within the VM. https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox/  If you have a specific issue with it, I might suggest asking in Hortonworks Support Forum